# Using .net PUT to IBM MQ queue no longer sending message

Tags: c#, .net, ibm-mq

In c#, `PUT` is no longer sending messages but the try catch is not throwing an error. I can not find a trace or error log on the client.  Please let me know where else to look for a clue to what has changed.

The client is on a Windows 2012 server and MQ is on a mainframe.

```
// in class constuctor
        try
        {
        _queueManager = new MQQueueManager(queueManagerName, channelName, connectionName);
        _requestQueue = _queueManager.AccessQueue(queueName, MQC.MQOO_OUTPUT | MQC.MQOO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING); //added  | MQC.MQOO_INQUIRE 
        }
        catch (MQException MQexp)
        {

            Console.WriteLine("Error:" + MQexp.Message);
            Console.Read();
        }
    public string Queue_PutTestMsgs(string message)
    {
        MQMessage queueMessage = new MQMessage();
        MQPutMessageOptions queuePutMessageOptions = new MQPutMessageOptions();
        try
        {


        queueMessage.Format = MQC.MQFMT_STRING;
        queueMessage.MessageType = MQC.MQMT_REQUEST;
        queueMessage.ReplyToQueueManagerName = _responseQueueManagerName;//added
        queueMessage.ReplyToQueueName = _responseQueueName;

        queueMessage.WriteString(message);
        _requestQueue.Put(queueMessage, queuePutMessageOptions);
        }
        catch (MQException MQexp)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error:" + MQexp.Message);
            Console.Read();
        }
        return message;
    }
```

Comment: The only question that springs to mind is, do you know for sure that this would throw an `MQException`? Maybe try catching other exceptions too.

Comment: Don't see a problem in the code. If there was any MQ error, MQException would have been thrown. I hope you are calling "Queue_PutTestMsgs" method somewhere in your code :)